# Watching file change in node.js - Performance Issues

Tags: javascript, node.js, file, logging

I am currently trying to create a real time log monitoring tool in node.js with [Chokidar](https://github.com/paulmillr/chokidar) & socket.io. However i am not quite clear on how to effectively reload the content when the file is changed. Chokidar watches for the file change and triggers an event where the only option i have to get the changed content is to again read the entire file and populate again the view with that content. This really slows down the entire process and increases the CPU utilization too.

```
var watcher = chokidar.watch('file, dir, or glob', {
  ignored: /[\/\\]\./, persistent: true
});

watcher.on('change', function(path, stats) {
  if (stats) console.log('File', path, 'changed size to', stats.size);
});
```

In my case, the log size is too big and there are heavy updates to them. How should i go about to resolve this issue? Is there any way to just get the changed content rather than reloading the entire file to get the changed content?

Answer (score 0):

It does not appear that chokidar offers any features to tell you what changed in the file (it gives you the filename and file stats).

As such, if you wanted to know what changed, then the burden is on you to have maintained some sort of previous shadow copy of the file so that you can then analyze the new file vs. the previous copy to see what changed.  This is obviously quite a storage intensive task if you're doing this for a whole file system (requires double storage), but certainly could be manageable if you were just doing it for one small set of files.

Comment: Is there a way of doing this ? To watch a file which will just emit what data has been changed or modified.. Don't want to read the entire file here..

Comment: @Sathish - I'm not aware of any OS service that offers what you are asking for.  It would require journaling of all writes to the file such that they could be later used to determine changes.